# Knowing when your changes are reverted?

Tags: feature-request, edits

Is there a way to know if one of your edits to a post gets reverted?

If not, there should be

Comment: retagged :) Unless you check by hand, there's no way to know. At least if we're talking about someone else's post.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it shouldn't matter that much. You shouldn't take your edits personally. An edit can be reedited or reverted for too many reasons.
However, if you made a mistake while editing, it would be nice to [contact you via @comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him).

Comment: I was thinking about that because I edited a post that were doing advertisment for a website while asking a question. Like "I'm working for www.blah.com, a great site for X and Y and my question is...". The question was valid and interesting so I didn't close, but I removed the self-advertisment part... and I don't want them to put it back ^^

Comment: @marcgg - good call. I think flagging for moderator attention is best in this case, they'll notice (?) if it happens more than once.

Comment: I don't think the guy asking the question wanted to spam or anything, I felt like he was just really proud of his product :) So I didn't flag and just left a comment