# @comment notification and Editing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-replies, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow post editor to see @comments directed at him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him)

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376915/how-to-print-out-the-memory-contents-of-a-variable-in-c/2376921#2376921):

If someone makes an edit to an answer of mine, and I want to ask them about their edit, will the @name mechanism (or perhaps something else) alert them to my comment?

If not, this could be seen as a feature request, though it's not tremendously important.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if it worked with every person who has been active in the question; including posting another answer, casting a close vote, editing, etc.

Comment: It could be, but on the other hand I can see that getting a little out of hand. And sometimes when I vote to close I don't want to hear the OP whining about "how is this not allowed when question X is allowed?"

Comment: It also would play havoc with "large questions" (the subjective ones that eventually grow to 300+ answers before getting locked) and deciding who to notify.

Comment: well, it supports replying to editors now, at least