# Silk purse badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

[Silver] **Silk purse** - Edited someone else's question with a negative vote count which later reaches a score of 2 or greater before it is edited again by anyone else.

I'm reposting this [(see original)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/56652#56652) since the badge question was locked, thanks Ether for the name.

Comment: why was it locked?

Comment: @Juan: "Locking ... I can not find anything here .. its ridiculous. – waffles♦"

Comment: This doesn't seem like a silver badge, it's too easy

Comment: See discussion on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44582/should-there-be-a-badge-for-awesome-edits-on-questions/44587#44587

Comment: @Michael: The score requirements could be changed if it needs to be harder.

Comment: @Simon That would be good. The way it is now, someone could take a newly posted good question, downvote it to -1, edit it, reverse their vote to get the question at +1, and wait for one more upvote to get the badge. It probably needs limits in both directions, but something like "Edited a question with -5 votes" encourages people to wait until a question is downvoted before editing it, which is also bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great idea! Finally we have an incentive to not give up on people and encouragement to generate great questions from confused seeds.

I seriously love the idea.

I don't necessarily think the implementation will work.

1. This may encourage people to *completely* change the question, rather than just reform it.
2. There are some questions which actually *need* to be closed. If they are offensive or abusive, we would want the user to be punished for the behaviour, not rewarded with upvotes.
3. This could also be gamed by piggy-backing on someone else's edit.
4. Because the OP is still getting upvotes, they haven't really learned any sort of lesson about writing good posts.

Answer (score 2):

I think implementation problems like the ones in [devinb's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/silk-purse-badge/58813#58813) were the reason this failed the last time it came up, but there wasn't much discussion about it. I really would like to see this happen, because people have a bad habit of seeing a poorly worded but perfectly valid question and moving their mouse straight past "edit" to "close", which I would very much like to discourage. It becomes a race, where the editors try to fix up the question before the closers get 5 votes in, because once the question is fixed the close votes will stop, but if it closes first it's almost impossible to reopen