# Voting up edits (by others) of my questions

Tags: feature-request, voting, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding incentive for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/adding-incentive-for-editing)

Is explicitly accepting the edit of my question by some other user by "voting up the revision" a good idea?

Such edits can contribute to the question a lot but the work goes uncounted.

I have "rollback" button if I disagree the edit (never occured yet), but don't have the opposite thing.

I think a good place for voting controls is near "edited 9 hours ago" label for myself (as I see what's changed without hints) and in stackoverflow.com/posts/.../revisions page for everyone else.

Comment: How do you vote up a revision?

Comment: @John Saunders I can't. This is a feature request.

Comment: What exactly would we get from voting on revisions? You can roll back if it was non-sense, if you agree simply leave it.

Comment: @gf, Simply leaving gives no advantage to the editor. I want the feature to support good edits by voting system, so users can edit other's questions not just to make them better, but also to gain points.

Comment: BTW: edits don't require "moderators" as such. Just a user with 2000 rep (100 for CW posts). By "moderator" we generally mean the guys with diamonds after their usernames. They have powers beyond the ken of mortal users.

Comment: @dmckee I mean users who can edit others' questions.

Comment: Possible duplicates (*at least a similar idea was discussed in them*): [Adding incentive for editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/) and [Rep for editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/rep-for-editing)

Comment: @Gnoupi Yes, it is the same. They wasn't showed up in similar questions list when I was entering this question.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. I've just improved a question and it got +3 upvotes. It would be nice if others could vote on my revision, it would be a great incentive for everyone to improve the content on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is unnecessary. There's a *lot* of editing happening on the sites and I don't think we need to reward editing with more rep, it seems to happen organically. I think that adding such a feature to vote up edits would be confusing and wouldn't have much benefit. As others have said, if you disagree with an edit, roll back, otherwise you agree :-)