# Reputation sharing after a post edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, review, edits

Consider the answer I posted here: [How to convert nanoseconds to seconds using the TimeUnit enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924208/how-to-convert-nanoseconds-to-seconds-using-the-timeunit-enum/16738065#16738065)

It is actually an improvement to the most upvoted answer. However, had I just made an edit to it (the most upvoted answer), I would have received no reputation for further upvotes. This way, however, I received 5 upvotes until now and even earned the Necromancer badge for it.

Do you think it would make sense if the editor could also earn **some** reputation for subsequent upvotes?

Perhaps this could be part of the edit review process, where the reviewer has e.g. a checkbox to tell whether this edit actually builds upon the original answer, so that the editor should also receive reputation for further upvotes.

Comment: Related: [Reputation for editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42882)

Comment: The difficulty would be telling what kind of edits deserve upvotes. If all I do is fix your grammar, do I deserve reputation for that?

Comment: @Mansfield as I already suggested, this could be part of the reviewing process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reputation for editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/reputation-for-editing)

Comment: I fear the subsequent "I think I deserve rep for my edits, but some ç"&"*%&*"() reviewers prevented this from happening" posts.

Comment: What if the edit is made by a 2k+ user, so isn't "reviewed"? Or are we sticking to the "2k users don't get squat for editing" thing? By the way, congrats on hitting 2k :)

Comment: @Geobits Perhaps the edit merit review could remain until 10k, after which you decide by yourself what kind of edit it was :) BTW thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I disagree - OP here wants reviewers (or editor) to decide if reward is due, not the OP of edited post.

Comment: @Mołot still close enough to be considered a dupe in my opinion.

Comment: @Zoltán So 10k+ users can decide for themselves whether they want to take some of someone else's reputation when they edit a post.  That couldn't ever be abused...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Neither of us is diamond, so let's see how voting will go ;) No point in arguing here any further. Even if not closed, I think we may safely assume this will not get implemented.

Comment: @Servy by sharing, I didn't mean taking someone's reputation, but rather **also** receiving reputation, where the person who originally answered gets rep as they normally would. Just wanted to clarify that. I agree that it could be abused.

Comment: @Zoltán Even so, it would encourage such users to go around to tons of popular questions and editing them just to get the rep.

Answer (score 4):

I'm against.

- If edit would change the meaning of a post (question or answer), it should be separate post.
- And if edit would not change meaning, then editor don't really deserve any reputation share.

Keeping reviews up to 10k, letting users decide when some of rep should be stripped from original poster and so on is just a huge - and unneeded - field for drama, arguments, and software errors in implementation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I wish everyone who disagrees posted an answer instead of downvoting the question.

Comment: @Zoltán [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Zoltán what Angew said - I would probably post it as a comment if not due to length, and I did downvoted, too. Nothing against you or against the technical quality of your proposal, but I don't agree with it.

Comment: @Zoltán I'm -15 down on a question already today. Don't take it personally. The Meta world takes no prisioners. But on the flip side, I'm 30 points up on an answer. My recommendation? Post some good answers before daring to ask another question!