# Are editors notified of @comment-replies?

Tags: support, notifications, editor, comment-replies

According to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61135/editor-comments-dont-point-to-the-post-the-comment-was-made-on), they should be but it's buggy.

Comment: What exactly is the bug?

Comment: @badp: A @editor notification without a link to the question. But my question is a dupe now anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Allow post editor to see @comments directed at him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him) - `[status-completed]`

Comment: Wouldn't that be a duplicate?

Comment: @Bobby: it's more a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work, which I just found.