# if a moderator edits my post, is there a way to ask them why?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-tags

A moderator edited my post by removing what I thought was a relevant tag.  Is there a way I can ask them directly why they did that?

Comment: comment and discuss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Ask them as a comment to your question.  I would hope that they would have commented when they edited...

Comment: They don't need to comment, actually. [Comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) [can work on any editors to the post as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055).

Comment: And if you use the @<username>, the user gets notified.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a question here with a link to the question is also a good way to discuss with others why the change was made.

I'm assuming you're talking about this change:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4738939/revisions

It is likely that the reason why `iphone-ui` was removed while `ipad-ui` was left alone was because `iphone-ui` is a new tag to stackoverflow, and the person who removed it did not feel it was necessary to add another tag.  The editor who changed it probably keeps an eye on newly created tags and removes those that seem unnecessary.

Personally, I would rather have it tagged `iphone` and `ui` rather than combining them primarily because we really don't need more specialized tags, and while the iOS user interface is a little unique, there are plenty of mobile devices which share similar ui design rules.

Comment: +1 for [iphone] and [ui] instead of some hybrid tag thingy

Comment: thanks; i'll put more thought into my tag selection from now on.  my approach has been to just choose suggested tags as i type, with little thought to the reach of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

If it was an actual diamond mod, you could flag that post with your query.  But if if was just a regular editor/tagger you will need to use the @<username> comment format to address them.

Comment: I'd really suggest that even if it was a diamond mod, you should just use the comment reply. Flagging implies there's attention needed to handle something. This is more of a request-for-comment.

Comment: @Grace, I agree.  I was just throwing out other options.