# Moderating Edits to Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

In the thread [How do I track down the cause of a StackOverflowException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879835/how-do-i-track-down-the-cause-of-a-stackoverflowexception-in-net/4879873#4879873), I find that George Stocker has made several edits to the question, removing hundreds of characters, in addition to editing just about every answer.

Yes, the OP does not have strong English skills and I believe George was just trying to make the question clearer, but this seems excessive to me. Moreover, the OP has complained that items he felt were relevant have been edited out.

I consider this improper use of the edit feature. Yet, I have no way to contact George, or to flag, report or otherwise try and fix this. Yes, I can revert but then I'd lose some more recent edits made by the OP.

Shouldn't there be some way to moderate the way people edit posts?

Comment: Actually, you can respond to any editor of a question using the same @syntax used for replying to comments. Not a full answer, but just a tip for the future.

Comment: He didn't post any comments--just edited everyone else's, so that wasn't an option.

Comment: I'm saying editors will receive those even if they haven't commented.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you feel was excessive about the edits?

Comment: I agree with Tim, I don't see any relevant information being removed by George in his edits. And the bit about "editing just about every answer" is a non sequitur unless you think those edits were excessive as well.

Comment: In this case, I think you're overreacting.  George's edits salvaged the original question, which led to it being reopened.  Looking at what was removed, I feel that he focused the question on the core issue.  He then tweaked the answers to improve code formatting, which made them clearer.

Comment: @Tim et. al., Removing half of a post, twice caused the OP to remark that parts of his comment that **HE** felt were relevant had been commented out. This is not respecting the OP, and would be very frustrating for anyone. @Brad: He didn't salvage anything. The problem turned out to be lack of information, not excess information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'll answer the base question:

> Shouldn't there be some way to moderate the way people edit posts?

There already is, in that other editors can always rollback the edit, and one of the 10k lists shows all recent edits. Requiring that *all* edits need approval (like the edit suggestion feature) is definitely not a good idea; the whole point of the [2k requirement for editing](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) is that users should know how to edit on their own by then. As [Grace Note already pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77794/moderating-edits-to-questions-and-answers#comment-189517), you can comment reply to an editor if you disagree with their edit ([as of May 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him))

Comment: If someone posts inappropriate questions or answers, I can flag them. I have no way to flag inappropriate editing.

Comment: @Jonathan But users don't have the ability to take care of bad posts any other way (besides downvoting, but they're still visible; 10k users can delete questions, but only after a couple days). Any 2k user can single-handedly take care of a bad edit

Comment: Yes, I guess. Note that I was never suggesting all edits should need approval.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, I misunderstood; I reread after your comment and saw the "or to flag, report or otherwise try and fix this"

Answer (score 2):

I edited that question because I felt like the Original poster deserved an answer, and I didn't want to see the question closed because of a communication issue.

Good editing improves communication.

Did any of my edits hinder communication? If so, you ought to let me know that (as others have mentioned, the @username syntax will do nicely).  If they improve communication, then it doesn't matter whether I make 1 edit or 100.

When I'm in a post, I generally don't just edit one little thing.  If there are answers that can be improved, I'll improve them.

Because of my edit, that question went from -[7 downvotes to +25 net upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4879835/timeline).  Do you need any more proof than that that I took the right course of action?

Comment: Taken to the extreme, you could edit it into a different question that is a better one and it might get more up votes. But that wouldn't respect the OP. As I recall the OP was frustrated that elements of the question were getting removed. I know how much that would annoy me. My view that the editing was excessive has not changed.

Comment: @Jonathan Are you sure you aren't projecting your personal feelings into this? I ask because I see no where where the OP expresses frustration with any edits.

Comment: I think I'm finished with this particular discussion but here's one of the OP's comments: `john rash is not incorrect i had more explanations but some edits removed all – PRASHANT P`