# If you put @username in a comment to a question, does it contact editors/voters?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-replies

If you put @username in a comment to a question,  does it contact editors/voters?  Because if it doesn't it should.  You should be able to ask a editor why he made a change. You should also be able to contact people who have voted to close a post and ask them to defend their decision,  or to recede their vote.

**edit:**
based on  Tshepang's comment can comments also be applied to users who have voted to close a question?

Comment: Here's how it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019

Comment: Not, not at all. That page should tell exactly how @user works, so if it didn't mention that voters are notified, then assume that they aren't.

Comment: Right, I mean that this is a feature that should be added.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him) indicates that editors are definitely contactable using the `@username` syntax. I doubt it applies to voters, but I'm not sure.

Comment: problem is that you can't see who voted to close until it's closed. If you really think it should be reopened you can always Flag it and explain why then moderator can re-open it instantly.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question "who gets notified", see [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

> There are some rules to follow for it to work:
>   1. Notifications apply to the **author, commentors, and editors** of the question or answer....

---

My thoughts on the feature request:

*to allow @notify comments on closed questions to notify users who cast votes to close*

1. It would result in those who cast close votes while doing cleanup of the site to receive an inordinate amount of noisy "Why U close me?" comments.
2. How many closed questions would automatically have five comments (one for each close vote) and something like this:

   - "@closer1: I've edited my post"
   - "@closer2: I've edited my post"
   - "@closer3: I've edited my post"
   - "@closer4: I've edited my post"
   - "@closer5: I've edited my post"
   - "@questionasker1: *You still aren't asking a real question*."
3. There are already steps you can take to [get reopen attention to your closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

Comment: You make a good point, but being able to anonymously contact `@downvoters` and `@closevoters` would still be a good idea IMO.

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, grouping them into a single @name would be _much_ less obtrusive. It still leaves #1 (noisy comments), but I can only guess at what the signal to noise ratio would be.

Comment: my feeling is it would be worth trying out.