# Notify close-voters when the OP adds a comment after the question was closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, closed-questions, notifications

I recently encountered a rather confused but well-intentioned new member.  This member asked a question that I and some others put on hold as too broad.  The new member then added a comment to the question asking for clarification, but because the comment didn't @-notify any of the closers, none of us saw the question.  I didn't learn that the member was confused until several days later when the member posted a follow-up Meta question asking about the post.

The close message instructs new users to "leave a comment" even though that comment may never be seen.

**So that close-voters can help to workshop salvageable questions, they should be notified when the OP adds a comment to the closed question.**

Comment: A possible topic for discussion is whether the close-voters should also be notified when *anyone* adds a comment to the closed question.

Comment: Just today several people voted to close a question as a duplicate that wasn't within light-years of being a duplicated.  And I found out they don't get notifications of comments.  One of them, when I managed to reached him, acknowledged that closing it was a mistake.  And I managed to reach several others by circuitous means, and the question was re-opened.  But generally those who close questions should be responsible participants in the community and not irresponsible drive-by shooters.  They should be notified of comments.

Comment: Since this post has been bumped I will add links to other posts which seem related (which are about *some kind* of notification to close voters):
[If you put @username in a comment to a question, does it contact editors/voters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81849) and [Notify close voters when a closed question gets edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56849).

Answer (score 7):

This would be a good way to help us be more friendly and helpful to new users. Good feature request. I agree with your reasoning that it is not good if new users leave such a comment and then nobody sees it. IMO a close vote comes with a little bit of responsibility. So getting a ping when the OP comments sounds reasonable. This will make it more likely that close-voters can offer some advice to the OP on how to improve the question and possibly have it reopened.  Or,  if the question is not salvageable, OP can be told that so that they don't waste time or post more similar questions.

Comment: Just a helpful tip, try to expand more on your answer rather than just simply stating that the request is acceptable

Comment: @PythonMaster Thanks for the tip, done.

Answer (score -7):

This feature is needed because there is a severe deficiency of communication between people who make it their business to close questions considered closable for some reason, and everyone else.

It is not the least bit unusual is that the closers are wrong: they close a question as off topic because they didn't understand it. Often that's because the question is not well expressed, but it's also not unusual that it's because of the ignorance of those who close it and the fact that they don't know they are ignorant of the topic.

**PS:** The user called "Servy" says its **"rare"** that those who close questions get it wrong because of ignorance of the topic. "Servy" would be right if that comment were about one of the stackexchange sites on which I've posted a lot, but wrong if it were another, on which I have a reputation of more than 175,000. On that one, closers getting wrong because of their own ignorance of the topic is not unusual.

Comment: It's not the *responsibility* of anyone else to fix the question author's question.  It's *their own* responsibility to fix it.  Some people may choose to help, and that's nice, but they're not the one's obligated to fix the question.  If the question is so unclear that people can't understand it, and think it's off topic as a result, then the question *still merits closure*.  A question being unclear *is a reason to close it* in it's own right.  If the question isn't well expressed *that's a problem* that the author needs to fix before the question can be answered.

Comment: @Servy : Have I attempted to assign any "responsibility" to fix the question to anyone? What if the question doesn't need fixing and those who vote to close it are in need of finding that out? That's not unusual.

Comment: You have assigned responsibility, yes.  You stated that users not fixing someone else's question for them is a problem.  It's not.  When they do do it's great, and we do want them to do it, but it's not a *problem* if they don't.  It *is* a problem when the question author decides not to.  A question being closed when it doesn't need fixing *is* very unusual, and there are lots of ways to deal with the very rare event when it happens.

Comment: @Servy : You seem to tacitly assume that those who close questions are right and the person who wrote a question that got closed are wrong. But no such infallibility exists in reality.

Comment: Last time I closed a question it showed a post notice with links to the relevant articles in the help center. Is that feature no longer there?

Comment: @rene : You miss the point. The help center won't help in cases where the people who close the question are wrong and the cause is their ignorance of the topic.

Comment: Oh, this is not about me then. I'm never wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No.  As I said in my comment, there are cases where questions are closed incorrectly, they're just rare.  You're just assuming that they're typically wrong, and you assume incorrectly.

Comment: @Servy : Why am I the one you're taking to task? I repeated an idea in the original posting above, and then added my own. You're objecting to the idea that was in the original posting.

Comment: @Servy : You say they're rare. WHICH stackexchange sites are you talking about? Those incidents are indeed rare on mathoverflow, which is a stackexchange site. They are NOT rare on math (dot) stackexchange (dot) com.

Comment: I've casted 62,222 close votes and I hope some of them resulted in the successful closure of a question. I don't want to be bothered by even a fraction of comments that would be generated in my inbox stating nothing more then *Why did you close my question, unfair!*

Comment: Well I *don't* support the original proposal, but your justification for it is *much* worse than the OP's, and also the OP hasn't been on the site since last year, so there's not much of a dialog to be had with them.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If a specific site has a specific problem with questions being inappropriately closed, that's an issue to bring up with that site's meta.

Comment: @Servy : Why is it worse? Ignorant people mistakenly closing questions is a substantial problem on math (dot) stackexchange (dot) com.

Comment: There's a mechanism built into the system to re-open a closed question. People with privileges to close can also vote to re-open. If five people disagree with a closure, they can easily make that known and get the question re-opened.

Comment: . . . . . and moreover, many of those habitually closing questions on math (dot) stackexchange (dot) com don't suspect that it's a substantial problem there because they never find out that anyone disagrees with them.

Comment: @ale : No they can't. They cannot make it know to those who close the question that they have made a mistake UNTIL the question actually gets closed.

Comment: Why do you (dot) the site? We know how to find it and if we click the link I don't think we'll bring it down due to a DDoS attack.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The OP is saying that they voted to close a question, wanted to be informed that a discussion ended up happening about it's closure, and didn't know to be included.  You're saying that question closures are mostly wrong and ought to be fixing the OP's question for them in the first place, and for that reason the site should have tools to annoy close voters about every question they've ever closed.  Hopefully you can see the difference in the justifications between those two things.

Comment: @rene : Because of some experiences with posting urls.

Comment: @Servy : I didn't say they're _mostly_ wrong; I said it's not unusual. The problem is that question-closers rarely find out that they don't know everything.

Comment: @MichaelHardy But it *is* unusual.  It's *very* unusual.  And despite being unusual, there are *lots* of tools in place to address and resolve that very unusual situation, and they work quite well.

Comment: @Servy : On math.stackexchange.com question-closers may get it right ninety percent of the time. Ten percent is not what I consider "rare".

Comment: @Servy : How do you know it unusual? How much experience do you have on math.stackexchange.com? And how would you find out if you got one wrong, when you get no feedback?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Again, if you think there's a specific problem with a specific site, then that's something to discuss on that site's meta.

Comment: @Servy : Probably most of those who close questions on math.stackexchange.com think the problem is very unusual there. They have no opportunity to learn the truth.

Comment: @MichaelHardy We can see network wide stats showing that the instances of it are *much* lower than you're suggesting, and for like the third time, if you want to discuss a specific problem with a specific site, go to that site's meta.

Comment: @rene : Are you entitled to claim you know about what WOULD happen when you haven't tried it? A woman gave birth to quintuplets and I haven't phoned her to tell her what that experience "would" be like, since I don't know.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It could be that a huge portion of the entire site doesn't understand what's appropriate, and votes to close good questions, or it could just be that *one* person doesn't understand the site's requirements and standards (or just doesn't like them).  Occam's razor leads me towards one direction, but like I've said many times, if that's what you actually want to discuss then *to to that site's meta* because that's the appropriate place to discuss it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Wait, you mean to suggest that you can never made predictions about *anything* that you haven't done personally, ever?  That's...just not true.  If someone tells you to go jump off of a bridge and another person advises against it because it might hurt you you don't say, "have you actually done it before, who are you to tell me what would happen if I jumped off of a bridge unless you've actually done it yourself".

Comment: @Servy : No, I'm not saying "never anything". But this proposal is remote from everyone's experience.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Not really.  It's easy enough to see how many comments are posted on questions that you've closed, and to realize that for many people that's a completely absurd number, way more than they could ever actually read or keep track of.  You don't need to actually have the feature to understand what the implications of it being there would be.

Comment: @MichaelHardy as with everything that is hard, just do it one at a time ... the posts that I keep an eye on or that I have moderated generated  enough noise to opt out of what you propose. Again, SO might be different but you seem to take this on the SE level in which case I won't support your endorsement of this feature

Comment: @rene : I'm not the one who brought the issue here.