# How should I ask a why a question has been edited?

Tags: discussion, edits

Sometimes, I see questions edited for purposes that are unclear to me, but I don't want to rollback because I may be misunderstanding its purpose. How should I request that the editor explains the reason for editing my post?

(If it helps, this is the concrete example that led me to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8911617/revisions.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno `@` notifiers do work for editors!  No autocomplete though.  And it's such a pain to spell kiamlaluno correctly =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Copy and paste works the same. `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno You mean you won't even consider changing your username for my personal convenience?  Oh fine, copy-paste it is =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 We can do so: You change your username to _kiamlaluno_, and I change it to _jadarnel27_. At least, you would not have any problem in referencing me. `;-)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Editors can see comments directed at them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him)

Just [leave a comment for skaffman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The only edit to the question you linked to is the removal of the [adwords-api-v201109](/questions/tagged/adwords-api-v201109) tag. You can check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8911617/revisions), to verify that.

There is (or should be) a comment explaining the edit, especially if it's a substantial one. If there isn't or you need clarifications you could always leave a comment to the editor using the `@username` format and ask for explanation on the edit.

For retags it would be preferable to search Meta first for mentions of the specific tag first. There could be an active cleanup process, and the related Meta questions sufficiently explain why the tag doesn't work.

Comment: I see that. I want to know why the tag was removed. How should I go about obtaining that reason?

Comment: @smp7d Sorry, I have a bad habit of writing the quick part of the answer and then immediately start to write the long part. I've added a suggestion for retags, you can always ask but search Meta first.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, the @-reference works for who edits a question too; if I edit your question, and you write a comment for the question that starts with *@kiamlaluno*, I get notified.

If you see that the same user keeps doing the same type of edit to most of your posts, such as adding the same URL to all of them, adding a sentence that is for a question that the user would ask, writing a comment inside the post you wrote, then you can ask a question here. That is not because you should not rollback the edit, but because somebody should say to that user that kind of edits are not welcome.