# Pinging someone who edited a post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, comment-replies

If someone edits a post of mine, and they have not commented on that post, I cannot ping them if I want to respond to or comment on their edit.  I can leave a comment and hope and pray and cross my fingers that they see it, but that only goes so far.

Could it be made possible to ping someone who edits a post, at least as an option to the author of the post (if not to everyone)?

Comment: One of the very few times that closing as a dupe of the big general question is appropriate.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate, but I am very glad it exists. I did not much fancy trawling through the big general question for the answer to this.

Answer (score 6):

[Editors are already notified of comments @-addressed to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him).

Comment notifications are a confusing beast, but you can read about all the gory details of how they work here: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: I am trying it on a post of mine that was edited, and the username of the editor does not come up.  Does it ping them nonetheless?

Comment: I assume this is the line in the linked answer that addresses my question - "Tab name completion can be used, and that knows when @name is unnecessary and will then not automatically complete names. It also does not work for editors." So that means I need to type it in, or it works even without typing it in?

Comment: @YEZ Auto-completion doesn't work for editors, but notifications do. You have to spell out their name (in a way that would normally trigger the notification - i.e. without spaces, etc.) or else it won't work.

Comment: Aha - is there a logic to that, or just to keep us on our toes?

Comment: @YEZ It's just too performance-intensive to comb through post history every time someone starts typing what looks like a username.

Comment: @AnnaLear The server could provide the list of editors somewhere in an easy to search format -- no need to go through the API for that. As it is, the UI clearly indicates "you can't @-notify that person" which effectively nullifies the feature.