# Anti tags - Valid use or not?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I just came across this [[not-jquery]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-jquery) tag.

Personally, I think this is poor use of the tagging system. The question already states that the user wants a solution that does not require jQuery. Tagging it as such doesn't provide any extra classification benefits. If it's not jQuery related, it just shouldn't be tagged [jquery].

(Following this same pattern I could also tag this question "not-waffles".)

<strike>Should I remove it?</strike> (done)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed. Your essential argument has been [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27666/questions-with-tag-not-programming-related-is-closed-by-marking-it-as-not-pro/27667#27667) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged).

I've gone ahead and removed those tags, since [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511681/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-text-input-entry-to-numbers-lowercase-letters-and) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033184/javascript-getelementsbycustomtagvalue) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876115/how-can-i-determine-if-a-div-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom) used it.

(Copied from my now-deleted comments, which also means this answer might be accepted and the question doesn't have to linger in unanswered status as far as the system is concerned.  Though I suppose it could be closed as a duplicate or too localized.)

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to be the odd one here and say that it is marginally valid to use anti-tags. The use being for something like `How do I apply a CSS selector with javascript` and of course, 3 or 4 people will probably suggest some very simple jQuery code. If their boss doesn't allow them to use jQuery, then that answer is not helpful.

In this case, I'd say it's ok to apply anti-tags.. They do look kinda weird though...

Comment: Do you find a problem with explaining in the question body that not using jQuery is desired?  That is a much more appropriate place to include that information where it can be clear and other requirements laid out.

Comment: Yes, I've asked such questions and said `I do not wish to include a javascript framework` and I got both jquery and YUI answers..

Comment: jQuery might not be helpful to the OP, but it will be to many (most?) people who find the answers later.  I think it's better to direct people away from a specific solution in the body of the question, but not totally exclude it from the answers.